# Why is access denied when I try to move a directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5, directoryinfo

I have two directories: folder1 and folder2.  folder1 contains a file.  I'd like to move folder1 under folder2 to result in folder2\folder1.  When I try to do this with the C# code below, I get:

> System.IO.IOException: Access to the path 'E:\www\dev\test\MoveDirectories\folder1' is denied.

The relevant code:

```
// In Page_Load.
MoveDirectory("folder1");

// Method for moving directories.
protected void MoveDirectory(string strMoveThis)
{
    try
    {
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(strMoveThis));
        dir.MoveTo(Server.MapPath("\\folder2\\"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex);
    }
}
```

My ASP.NET 4.0 app pool has modify privileges on the folder1.  This is actually a test application with code that has been pulled from a much bigger application, so it doesn't have all of the testing and exception handling one would expect.

**EDIT:** I found that I can create files within folder1.

Comment: is it possible another process has the file locked?

Comment: If you have the File Exporer open try closing it.  The process might be locking up the folders.

Comment: @tezromania: I was thinking that, but I believe I have closed every process that could be using the folder.

Comment: Can you move it by hand? Does a copy work?

Comment: @Chris Yessir.  I can move folder1 by mouse or by `move folder1 folder2`.

Comment: What about if you debug your program up to the error line in your code and then once your code reaches that point, are you still able to move it by hand? I'm curious as to whether or not other areas in your code are locking the files in folder1 during execution.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to answer my own question, but...

Basically, I updated this:

```
dir.MoveTo(Server.MapPath("\\folder2\\"));
```

to this:

```
dir.MoveTo(Server.MapPath("folder2\\" + strMoveThis));
```

Same permissions, but a better formation of the path.  Thanks for your help, everyone!